# Unit not changing back to Fahrenheit from Celcius value in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

In my Reactjs Weather project, I created toggle switch button which changes unit from Celcius (C) to Fahrenheit (F). From C to F works fine but doesn't switch back to F to C, only letter on button changes from C to F and vice-versa, but, not unit. See below code for reference

1. App.js (Parent File)

```
class App extends React.Component  { 
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      unit: 'C'
    }

  componentDidMount = async () => {
      // Tracking the location and 
      // Setting the state of latitude and longitude values
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(async (position) => {
        this.setState({
          lat:  position.coords.latitude.toFixed(3),
          lon: position.coords.longitude.toFixed(3)
        }, () => {
            this.fetchWeather()
        })

      },
      (error) => {
        toast.error(`${error.message}`,{
          autoClose: 3000
        });
    },
      {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: 50000,
        maximumAge: 1000
      })  
  }

 onUnitChange = (newUnit) => {
    this.setState({
        unit: newUnit
    }, () => {
      this.fetchWeather()
    })
}

fetchWeather = async () => {
    const unitType = (this.state.unit === 'C') ? 'M' : 'I';

    // First it changes from M to I and then it doesn't change
    console.log('UNIT TYPE', unitType)
  }

render() {

   return (
         <Weather
                changeUnit={this.onUnitChange}
                unit={this.state.unit}
          />
   )
 }
}

export default App
```

2. Weather.js

```
const Weather = props => {

const sendNewUnitToParent = (newUnit) => {
        props.changeUnit(newUnit); 
    }
return <div>
           <CelToFahrBtn 
              onUnitChange={sendNewUnitToParent}
              unit={props.unit}
           />
       </div>

}

export default Weather
```

3. CelToFahrBtn.js

```
class CelToFahrBtn extends Component {
    state = {
        celOn: true
    }

    changeUnit = (e) => {
        this.setState({ celOn: !this.state.celOn });
        const newUnit = e.target.textContent;
        this.props.onUnitChange(newUnit);
        console.log('UNIT CHANGED', newUnit)
      };

    render() { 
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
            <div
              onClick={this.changeUnit} className="CelSwitchWrap">
              <div className={"CelSwitch" + 
              (this.state.celOn ? "" : " transition")}>
                        <h3>°C</h3>
                        <h3>°F</h3>
               </div>
            </div>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}

export default CelToFahrBtn
```

So, this is all the required code for toggle switch button. Any changes or suggestions highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you passing the data you think you are?

Comment: Yes I am passing the data, but, it's not toggling the value

Comment: I mean from celcius to fahrenheit but not vice-versa

Comment: What is the text content of the target?

Comment: Its C or F based on toggle switch click

Comment: Is it? You’ve logged that to verify? Where dit’s the degree symbol disappear to?

Answer (score 0):

To make it simple, you can just use to formula for Celsius to Fahrenheit and the formula for Fahrenheit to Celsius. Then you could easily plug in the input and get the expected output. I would believe that this technique will be easier and more efficient.

Fahrenheit to Celsius:

```
function fah_to_cel (fahrenheit_input) {
    return (fahrenheit_input - 32) * 5 / 9
}
```

Celsius to Fahrenheit:

```
function cel_to_fah (celsius_input) {
    return (celsius_input * 9 / 5) + 32
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the response, but, where to use it, I mean in toggle switch or in Parent component

Comment: In the Parent Component, therefore you would access to function and easily call it.